# Read and tabulate table-like data from website

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe

I want to tabulate and store into Pandas this linked data from the [U.S. Weather Service](https://water.weather.gov/ahps2/crests.php?wfo=jan&gage=jacm6&crest_type=historic).

Here are the first four lines of the webpage.

> Historic Crests
>
> (1) 43.28 ft on 04/17/1979
>
> (2) 39.58 ft on 05/25/1983
>
> (3) 36.67 ft on 02/17/2020

You can access the data from an IDE or notebook using the following code.

```py
import bs4
import urllib.request
link = "https://water.weather.gov/ahps2/crests.php?wfo=jan&gage=jacm6&crest_type=historic"

webpage=str(urllib.request.urlopen(link).read())
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(webpage)

print(soup.get_text())
```

The data is already in a table-like structure, and I think you could tabulate it by parsing it into a dictionary of lists and then uploading it into a Pandas Dataframe. However, I imagine that there is a more simple *pythonic* approach.

Here's a snippet of the desired table structure.

| No. | Crest | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 43.28 | 04/17/1979 |
| 2 | 39.58 | 05/25/1983 |
| 3 | 36.67 | 02/17/2020 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a *regex* pattern and feed it to [`Series.str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html). E.g.:

```
tbl = soup.find('div', class_='water_information')
vals = tbl.get_text().split(r'\n')

df = pd.Series(vals).str.extractall(r'\((?P<No>\d+)\)\s(?P<Crest>\d+.\d+)\sft\son\s(?P<Date>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})')\
    .reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)

    No  Crest        Date
0    1  43.28  04/17/1979
1    2  39.58  05/25/1983
2    3  36.67  02/17/2020
3    4  36.30  03/31/1902
4    5  36.30  12/05/1880
..  ..    ...         ...
86  87  30.30  04/20/1955
87  88  30.26  01/25/1983
88  89  30.26  04/07/1981
89  90  30.25  01/24/2020
90  91  30.23  12/23/1967
```

And maybe change the dtypes at this point:

```
df['No'] = df.No.astype(int)
df['Crest'] = df.Crest.astype(float)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

Comment: fantastic. This is much cleaner than the for-loop I was using. Thank you!